# How to create a column/rows report in SQL 2005 Reporting Services?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, service, reporting

In SQL Reporting Services 2005 SP3, we have the following tabular report:

```
JobName       Product      Weight Processed      Start                 End
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2284          30mm         128 kg                11:55 04/09/2012      14:34 04/09/2012
3686          15mm         234 kg                19:21 03/09/2012      00:23 04/09/2012
```

We want to convert this into a columns/rows type report, e.g.:

```
JobName                  2284                3686
-------------------------------------------------------------
Product                  30mm                15mm
Weight Processed         128 kg              234 kg
Start                    11:55 04/09/2012    19:21 03/09/2012 
End                      14:34 04/09/2012    00:23 04/09/2012
```

How can we do this in SRS 2005?  We originally created the report as 'tabular' using the wizard.  We've tried using the matrix style and have selected JobName as the column and the rest of the fields as the rows, but it doesn't let us proceed without an entry in Details, but this view isn't giving us what we want.  It's listing the JobName repeating as columns but not listing the other fields as rows underneath.

Can anyone help on how we need to set up the report?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a *natural* matrix report. It is a report displaying horizontal data with fixed rows and group by `Job Name`.

You can see how do it here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrishays/archive/2004/07/23/horizontaltables.aspx